# Getting annotation from constructor value parameter using kotlinpoet-metadata

Tags: kotlinpoet

I have data class like this

```
@Tagme("Response")
@TagResponse
data class Response(
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val label: String,
    val images: List<String>,

    @Input(Parameter::class)
    val slug: Slug
)
```

Using annotation processor, I was able to get `Response` properties using this approach:

```
val parentMetadata = (element as TypeElement).toImmutableKmClass()

parentMetadata.constructors[0].valueParameters.map { prop ->

   // this will loop through class properties and return ImmutableKmValueParameter
   // eg: id, title, label, images, slug.

   // then, I need to get the annotation that property has here.
   // eg: @Input(Parameter::class) on slug property.

   // if prop is slug, this will return true.
   val isAnnotationAvailable = prop.hasAnnotations

   // Here I need to get the annotated value
   // val annotation = [..something..].getAnnotation(Input::class)
   // How to get the annotation? So I can do this:
   if ([prop annotation] has [@Input]) {
      do the something.
   }
}
```

Previously I tried to get the annotation like this:

```
val annotations = prop.type?.annotations
```

But, I got empty list even `isAnnotationAvailable` value is `true`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotations are only stored in metadata if they have nowhere else they can be stored. For parameters, you must read them directly off of the `Parameter` (reflection) or `VariableElement` (elements API). This is why we have the `ClassInspector` API. You almost never want to try to read anything other than basic class data. Anything that's already contained in the bytecode or elements is basically never duplicated into metadata as well. Treat metadata as added signal, not a wholesale replacement.

Comment: There is no `.annotations` on `ImmutableKmValueParameter`.

Comment: I found this: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/announcing-kotlinx-metadata-jvm-library-for-reading-modifying-metadata-of-kotlin-jvm-class-files/7980/30?u=ptdede

So, we can't read annotation via metadata right? So this is why. So sad. T.T

Comment: That comment is about `@file:` annotations, not annotations in general. You're right, I misremembered the API at first. Annotations are only stored in metadata if they have nowhere else they can be stored. For parameters however, you must read them directly off of the Parameter or VariableElement. This is why we have the `ClassInspector` API. I've edited the answer with this as well.

Comment: In the end I'm using elements API and it works! Thank you soo much

Comment: Upvoted because, after hours of research, I did not read about this anywhere else. I wonder why this kind of information is not more easily accessible. I guess all Kotlin meta-programming tools are still very new...